# Asymptotic density of Zhang's primes

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, twin-primes, prime-gaps

By this point, it is well known that Yitang Zhang's result implies for some $c$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+c$ is also prime, and that the smallest such $c$ is less than $70,000,000$ (which was reduced to $246$ thanks to all who worked on the Polymath Project).

I'm wondering if anyone has extended this to determine the asymptotic density of these primes, even though we don't know the precise value of $c$.

Thanks in advance for your comments

Comment: $246$???? Only $244$ more for a fields medal!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{H}_m$ is an admissible tuple of size $m$, as in the language of Zhang-Tao-Maynard-Polymath. For instance, $(t, t+2, t+6)$ is an admissible $3$-tuple. Then the results of Zhang-Tao-Maynard-Polymath have shown the existence of some $k(m)$, depending only on the size of $m$, such that there are infinitely many $t$ for which admissible $k$-tuples have at least $m$ simultaneous primes.

János Pintz, in his paper *Polignac Numbers, Conjectures of Erdős on Gaps between Primes, Arithmetic Progressions in Primes, and the Bounded
Gap Conjecture*, shows that this $k$ also gives a lower bound on the density, in the sense that there are at least
$$ \Omega\left(\frac{X}{\log^{k(m)}(X)}\right)$$
$k$-tuples with $t \leq X$ with $m$ simultaneous primes. Asymptotically, this means that the density of such $m$-simultaneous primes is at least
$$ \frac{c}{\log^{k(m)}(X)}$$
for some constant $c$.

For example, suppose that $k(3) = 1000$, meaning that admissible $1000$-tuples have $3$ simultaneous primes infinitely often. Then in fact the density of such an infinite configuration (which we do not know) is something like
$$ \frac{1}{\log^{1000}(X)}.$$

Of course, we expect the true density to be much more like
$$ \frac{1}{\log^3 (X)}.$$

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, Pintz showed (in addition to the Polymath's results) that if $P(X)$ is the number of $t\leq X$ for which there are at least $2$ simultaneous primes in an admissible $k(2)$-tuple (starting at $t$), then $P(x)$ grows at least as fast as $\frac{X}{log^{k(2)}(X)}$ (where $k(2)$ is at most $246$).  Is that right?

Comment: @JasonM yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I'm also curious about any big O results as well.

Comment: @JasonM The known Big-O result is the optimal one, $X/\log^2(X)$ for $2$-tuples. This follows from a sieving argument similar to the one frequently repeated as giving the heuristic asymptotics.